# calling almost same function

Tags: java, function, parameters, repeat

[image]

I am making a print star function like above.

I solved it but I wander I could make my code more efficient.

In my class, I have total 4 functions.

1. printFullstar
2. printHollowstar
3. printstarline1
4. printstarline2

The functions `1.printFullstar` and `2.printHollowstar`
have exactly same structure except the fact that they are calling the functions `3.printstarline1` and `4.printstarline2` each.

I wonder if I could make: 1, 2 function to one and just give parameter to call `3.printstarline1` or `4.printstarline2`

![enter image description here][2]

```
        System.out.println("(i)");
        printFullstar(input);
        System.out.println("(ii)");
        printHollowstar(input);

        /*
         * How do I utilize or pass BiFunction as an argument? int i = 0;
         * System.out.println("test1"); printS(input, new BiFunction<Integer,
         * Integer, Void>() );
         */

    }


    // longest width of star = input
    // shortest width of star  (double) input>2
    public static void printFullstar(int input) {

        int middle = 0;

        // when input is odd
        if (input % 2 == 1) {

            middle = 1;

            // the top part, let's print from 1 to longest(input) -- 1 5 9 3 7 11
            for (int i = 1; i <= input; i += 4) {
                printStarline1(i, input);
                if (i + 2 == input) {
                    printStarline1(input, input);
                    middle = i;
                }
                if (i + 4 == input)
                    middle = i;
            }

            // the first middle part
            // let's print from second longest line to shortest (>input/2)
            for (int i = middle;; i -= 4) {
                printStarline1(i, input);
                if (i - 4 < (double) input / 2) {
                    middle = i; // the shortest line
                    break;
                }
            }
            // the second middle part
            for (int i = middle + 4; i < input; i += 4) {
                printStarline1(i, input);
                middle = i;
            }

            // the bottom part, let's print from the longest line to 1
            for (int i = middle; i >= 1; i -= 4) {
                if (i + 2 == input || i + 4 == input)
                    printStarline1(input, input);
                printStarline1(i, input);
            }

        }//input odd end

        // when input is even
        if (input % 2 == 0) {

            middle = 2;

            // the top part, let's print from 2 to longest(input) 
            for (int i = 2; i <= input; i += 4) {
                printStarline1(i, input);
                if (i + 2 == input) {
                    printStarline1(input, input);
                    middle = i;
                }
                if (i + 4 == input)
                    middle = i;
            }

            // the first middle part
            // let's print from second longest line to shortest (>input/2)
            for (int i = middle;; i -= 4) {
                printStarline1(i, input);
                if (i - 4 < (double) input / 2) {
                    middle = i; // the shortest line
                    break;
                }
            }
            // the second middle part
            for (int i = middle + 4; i < input; i += 4) {
                printStarline1(i, input);
                middle = i;
            }

            // the bottom part, let's print from the longest line to 2
            for (int i = middle; i >= 2; i -= 4) {
                if (i + 2 == input || i + 4 == input)
                    printStarline1(input, input);
                printStarline1(i, input);
            }

        }//input even end

    }//print fullstar end

    // same as printFullstar() but use printStarline2
    public static void printHollowstar(int input) {

        int middle = 0;

        // when input is odd
        if (input % 2 == 1) {

            middle = 1;

            // the top part, let's print from 1 to longest(input) -- 1 5 9 3 7 11
            for (int i = 1; i <= input; i += 4) {
                printStarline2(i, input);
                if (i + 2 == input) {
                    printStarline2(input, input);
                    middle = i;
                }
                if (i + 4 == input)
                    middle = i;
            }

            // the first middle part
            // let's print from second longest line to shortest (>input/2)
            for (int i = middle;; i -= 4) {
                printStarline2(i, input);
                if (i - 4 < (double) input / 2) {
                    middle = i; // the shortest line
                    break;
                }
            }
            // the second middle part
            for (int i = middle + 4; i < input; i += 4) {
                printStarline2(i, input);
                middle = i;
            }

            // the bottom part, let's print from the longest line to 1
            for (int i = middle; i >= 1; i -= 4) {
                if (i + 2 == input || i + 4 == input)
                    printStarline2(input, input);
                printStarline2(i, input);
            }

        }//input odd end

        // when input is even
        if (input % 2 == 0) {

            middle = 2;

            // the top part, let's print from 2 to longest(input) 
            for (int i = 2; i <= input; i += 4) {
                printStarline2(i, input);
                if (i + 2 == input) {
                    printStarline2(input, input);
                    middle = i;
                }
                if (i + 4 == input)
                    middle = i;
            }

            // the first middle part
            // let's print from second longest line to shortest (>input/2)
            for (int i = middle;; i -= 4) {
                printStarline2(i, input);
                if (i - 4 < (double) input / 2) {
                    middle = i; // the shortest line
                    break;
                }
            }
            // the second middle part
            for (int i = middle + 4; i < input; i += 4) {
                printStarline2(i, input);
                middle = i;
            }

            // the bottom part, let's print from the longest line to 2
            for (int i = middle; i >= 2; i -= 4) {
                if (i + 2 == input || i + 4 == input)
                    printStarline2(input, input);
                printStarline2(i, input);
            }

        }//input even end
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which language are you using? Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Hello, I am using java. and my code is like above. I edited it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: [what kinds of questions can I ask[(https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Remember, we need [Minimal, complete, Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you are finished, click `edit` to edit your question, so that we may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you make this code more simple by and efficient by using interfaces.

1.)  create interface call **printBehaviour** first.

```
public  interface  PrintBehavious  {

    public  void printStarline(int num, int input);
}
```

2.) create two classes to override printStarline methods and implement the printBehaviour interface and inherit the printStar class :
  --> print1 :

```
public class print1 extends PrintStar implements PrintBehavious{

    @Override
    public void printStarline(int num, int input) {

        int blank = (input - num) / 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= blank; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        // except the top and bottom there should be two *
        System.out.print("*");
        if (num > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= num - 2; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= blank; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }


    }
--> print2 : 
public class print2  extends  PrintStar implements PrintBehavious{
    @Override
    public void printStarline(int num, int input) {

        int blank = (input - num) / 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= blank; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= blank; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }




}
```

3) create print interface :

```
public interface Print  {

      public  void printHollowstar(int input);

}
```

4). creat PrintStar class and implements Print interface and printBehaviour interface :

```
public   class PrintStar   implements Print , PrintBehavious{

    @Override
    public void printHollowstar(int input) {

        int middle = 0;
        // when input is odd
        if (input % 2 == 1) {
            middle = 1;
            // the top part, let's print from 1 to longest(input) -- 1 5 9 3 7 11
            for (int i = 1; i <= input; i += 4) {
                printStarline(i, input);
                if (i + 2 == input) {
                    printStarline(input, input);
                    middle = i;
                }
                if (i + 4 == input)
                    middle = i;
            }

            // the first middle part
            // let's print from second longest line to shortest (>input/2)
            for (int i = middle;; i -= 4) {
                printStarline(i, input);
                if (i - 4 < (double) input / 2) {
                    middle = i; // the shortest line
                    break;
                }
            }
            // the second middle part
            for (int i = middle + 4; i < input; i += 4) {
                printStarline(i, input);
                middle = i;
            }

            // the bottom part, let's print from the longest line to 1
            for (int i = middle; i >= 1; i -= 4) {
                if (i + 2 == input || i + 4 == input)
                    printStarline(input, input);
                printStarline(i, input);
            }

        }//input odd end

        // when input is even
        if (input % 2 == 0) {

            middle = 2;

            // the top part, let's print from 2 to longest(input) 
            for (int i = 2; i <= input; i += 4) {
                printStarline(i, input);
                if (i + 2 == input) {
                    printStarline(input, input);
                    middle = i;
                }
                if (i + 4 == input)
                    middle = i;
            }

            // the first middle part
            // let's print from second longest line to shortest (>input/2)
            for (int i = middle;; i -= 4) {
                printStarline(i, input);
                if (i - 4 < (double) input / 2) {
                    middle = i; // the shortest line
                    break;
                }
            }
            // the second middle part
            for (int i = middle + 4; i < input; i += 4) {
                printStarline(i, input);
                middle = i;
            }

            // the bottom part, let's print from the longest line to 2
            for (int i = middle; i >= 2; i -= 4) {
                if (i + 2 == input || i + 4 == input)
                printStarline(input, input);
                printStarline(i, input);
            }

        }//input even end

    }

    @Override
    public void printStarline(int num, int input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

05) and create a main class and print it I didn't import the scanner or any user import if u need u can make it :

```
public class Assignment1_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print1 l =  new print1();
        l.printHollowstar(3);

        print2 p =  new print2();
        p.printHollowstar(3);


    }

}
```

I didn't use proper naming just a demo code so if you need any clarification reply me. thanks, I think this would work fine

Comment: Wow it works perfect and it gave me motivation to learn OOP more.

Comment: your welcome bro. if you work hard on coding  you will get more interest god luck

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it either by using a boolean or enum. Because we want the code is readable to human, let's use enum.

Declare a enum for start type:

```
enum StarType {
  FULL, HOLLOW
}
```

Now, make the `printFullstar(int input)` and `printHollowstar(int input)` accept the enum variable as parameter:

```
public static void (int input, StarType starType) {
  ...
}

public static void printHollowstar(int input, StarType starType) {
  ...
}
```

Both method is receive the same parameters, hence we can simplify them by creating a method:

```
public static void printStar(int input, StarType starType) {
  ...
}
```

Now we have a general method to print a start. Let's simplify the body method.

From your code, we can found that the only different when calling `printStarline2(i, input)` and `printStarline(i, input)` is the name. Both receive the same parameters. So, we can create a method that choose which star to print by the StarType. Here we use our previous `StarType` enum. Create a method that receive `StarType` as parameter like this:

private static void printStarline(i, input, StarType starType) {
   ...
}

You can use it to determine which method to use by adding the code for checking the `StarType`:

```
private static void printStarline(i, input, StarType starType) {
   if(starType == StarType.FULL) {
     printStarline(i, input);
   } else if(starType == StarType.HOLLOW) {
     printStarline2(i, input);
   }
}
```

Now, you can change  `printStarline2(i, input)` and `printStarline(i, input)` to `printStarline(i, input, StarType starType)`.

Finally, you can use the code like this:

```
System.out.println("(i)");
printFullstar(input);
printStar(input, StarType.FULL)
System.out.println("(ii)");
printStar(input, StarType.HOLLOW);
```

Comment: I was able to follow it very easily. Thanks again.